# how to add display_name

Tags: php

how to add display_name to this request please

```
 $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT  a.post_title, m1.meta_value AS total, m2.meta_value AS titre, m3.meta_value AS date
FROM  wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m1
    ON a.ID = m1.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m2
    ON a.ID = m2.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m3
    ON a.ID = m3.post_id
WHERE a.post_type='post' 
AND m1.meta_key='total_des_prises'
AND m2.meta_key='titre'
AND m3.meta_key='date';
 " );

while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{var_dump($donnees);
?>
<br>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running a `WP_Query` or something similar instead of a raw query?

Comment: this can be done via `WP_Query`, this query is always going to be slow, but at least with `WP_Query` you gain the advantages of `WP_Cache` as well as plugin and object cache integration. For example if Elastic search was integrated this query would not get faster because it's raw SQL, even though Elastic search could have ran the query hundreds of times faster

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but I just realized that the request is not good ... indeed for the moment I have 3 authors and only one author to post 150 outputs ... and I end up with 450 outputs

Comment: I absolutely need a sql request

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I just realized that the request is not good ... there is a problem with display_name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add display\_name from the users table to this query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/398952/how-to-add-display-name-from-the-users-table-to-this-query)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the same situation you are also asking in [how to add display_name from the users table to this query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/398952/how-to-add-display-name-from-the-users-table-to-this-query) - yes?  You can see my answer there.

Comment: Hello
yes indeed, it is an error. a very very very big thank you for the solution.