# how to add display_name from the users table to this query

Tags: php

how to add display_name from wordpress users table to this query
thanks for the help

```
SELECT a.post_title, b.meta_key, b.meta_value as level, c.meta_value as intro
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.ID = b.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON a.ID = c.post_id
WHERE b.meta_key = 'level'
AND c.meta_key = '_post_main_intro'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this, by adding in another join, and selecting the `display_name` column from that joined table:

```
SELECT a.post_title, b.meta_key, b.meta_value as level, c.meta_value as intro, u.display_name
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.ID = b.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON a.ID = c.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_users u ON a.post_author = u.ID
WHERE b.meta_key = 'level'
AND c.meta_key = '_post_main_intro'
```

Hopefully this works for you!

Comment: Hello
a very very very big thank you for the solution. is it possible to filter that the published posts

Comment: @flexi2202 sure, you should be able to add another clause to the WHERE like `AND a.post_status = 'publish'`

Comment: a big thank you; it works wonderfully